# SUPEE8788 Issues with Get Payment Update (after suspected fraud cleared)

Tags: supee-8788

After Applying SUPEE8788 Patch for magento 1.9.2.2, Get Payment Update no longer retrieves update from Authorize.net.  Status is "There is no update for the payment." and it shows nothing in the authorize.net logs.  I know the patch was just release but has anyone else come across this?